# org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Exception while analyzing expression

Tags: android, kotlin, plugins, android-gradle-plugin, frontend

I run a kotlin project successfully on my desktop, but when I import the same project on my laptop and when I rebuild the project, it's throwing "org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Exception while analyzing expression".

As suggested in net, I tried with clean build, invalidate cache and restart. I deleted the cache folders and logs but no results.
I have tried Googling, but found no answer for this particular problem.

**Details:**
**Current kotlin plugin version: 1.3.61-release-Studio3.5-1**, latest version of plugin is installed, using **Android Studio 3.5.2**

Any help is apreciated!

Answer (score 6):

[image: Update Kotlin Plugin for Android Studio]

I was facing a similar error, updating Kotlin Plugin and restarting Android Studio fixed the issue for me

Comment: Thanks. Just restarting the Android Studio worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a sync issue. To solve this, I performed these two steps in succession and then re-ran the project:

- Deleted the entire build folder
- Build > Clean-Project

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was missing some jar files that were required for the app to build. So if you encounter this, check if you have all required dependencies on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was broken xml layout file (the expection message did not indicate the file).